# how does Mockito.when().return() works

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying mockito with Junit for the first time. I have written test method to test students details. Below is code, Please help me in understanding better, I have created studentService Mock object, and calling it go get student details. I am getting test passed, But I am not sure whether I am doing right or not

```
@mock
StudentService client;

@Test

    public void testGetStudentDetails() throws Exception {
            Student  student= new Student()
            student.setCustomerId("123");
            student.setRId("234");
            student.setClassNumber("100");
            Mockito.when(client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234")).thenReturn(student);
            Student sd=client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234");
            assertNotNull(sd);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking; could you reword?

Comment: Mockito.when(client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234")).thenReturn(student);
            Student sd=client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234");
assertNotNull(sd);

Is this right way to check assert Null?

Comment: Are you asking if `assertNotNull` is the correct way to assert that something isn't null?

Comment: What do you want to test? in your code you tests that mockito will return the given student. You should test your own code...

Comment: No, this test is imo not correct or at least "not useful". You're only testing that mockito works. You don't need to do this, its developers will do that. Instead test your own code. Means for this specific test: don't mock the `#getStudentDetails` method and use a real `Client` instance.

Comment: sorry for my bad English. Basically I a m new bee for the mockito. What I understand is, 

when I call
Student sd=client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234"); This will Invoke mmockito mock object  which will return  students object.
student sd will contain, returned object.
Now I will asert whether its null or not

Comment: And what have you tested with this? Only that `Mockito.when` does what it is supposed to do. Why do you want to test is? Check to see that you can use Mockito? Then you can do this, but you shouldn't keep that test after you've checked that Mockito works with your code.

Answer (score 4):

This test doesn't make much sense right now.

In your setup you tell the mock how to behave:

```
Mockito.when(client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234")).thenReturn(student);
```

And in your actually test you call the mock, and check that it did what you told it to do:

```
Student sd=client.getStudentDetails(new Long(123), "1234");
assertNotNull(sd);
```

So you are only testing Mockito, which I assume is not what you intended.

Assuming you want to test `getStudentDetails` you don't need Mockito for this as far as we can tell, just create a client, call the method and check that the thing happens, that is supposed to happen.

You will only mock things **used by** the object you want to test. (*) Since so far we see only the class you want to test and another class which is used, but doesn't need mocking since you simply created it, there is no need for mocking.

(*) This is a oversimplification, but will do for the beginning